# Мигает картинка при использовании blur

Tags: html, css, анимация, blur

При наведении курсора на картинку, добавляется с помощью `JS` `class` `.active`

В стиле `active`  указано, что картинка должно стать `blur(10px)` и `transform: translateY(20px);`

Анимация `active` выполняется отлично, но если мы захотим убрать `active`, чтобы вернуть обычное состояние, то картинка мигает перед концом анимации...

Как можно исправить?

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста код к своему вопросу

Comment: @Denver Добро пожаловать на stackoverflow! Если ответ вам был полезен, отметьте его галочкой (около цифры) и/или плюсом. В противном случае не молчите, если что-то не устроило или непонятно в ответе, то напишите в комментарии.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сниппет для воспроизведения проблемы:

```js
for (let img of document.querySelectorAll('.test')) {
  img.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () { this.classList.add('active'); }); 
  img.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () { this.classList.remove('active'); }); 
}
```

```css
.test   { transition: all 0.3s ease-out; }
.active { filter: blur(10px); transform: translateY(20px); }
```

```html
<img class="test" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?image=11">
<img class="test" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?image=15">
<img class="test" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?image=16">
```

Причина - <del>ресурсоемкость размытия.

Соответственно, *на 100% решить проблему **невозможно***. Но,</del> можно применить <del>CSS-вуду</del> некоторые оптимизации, которые помогут в большинстве случаев.
**upd.:** После прочтения комментариев и проверки в Firefox (Win, Andr) и Opera (Win), делаю вывод что я ошибался относительно причин. Видимо, они все-таки в Chrome под винду и андроид.

---

Вариант решения:

```js
for (let img of document.querySelectorAll('.test')) {
  img.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () { this.classList.add('active'); }); 
  img.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () { this.classList.remove('active'); }); 
}
```

```css
.test {
  transition: filter 0.3s steps(18),
              transform 0.3s ease-out; 
  backface-visibility: hidden !important; 
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1, 1); 
}
.active {
  filter: blur(10px); 
  transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0) scale(1, 1); 
}
```

```html
<img class="test" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?image=11">
<img class="test" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?image=15">
<img class="test" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?image=16">
```

Данное решение включает в себя (в порядке значимости):

- ограничение числа кадров перехода, `steps(18)`
  *60кадров/с (лимит браузера) * 0,3с = **18**

  Это также делает временн**у**ю функцию перехода линейной, что сильно ускоряет подсчеты (но это не просто аналог `linear`, а лучше).*
- отключение отрисовки оборотной стороны элемента через `backface-visibility: hidden`
  *Смысл очевиден: флип не выполняется => нет смысла рендерить оборотку.*
- исключение из пересчета `transform` трансформации по X и Z, а также масштабирования
  *Плюс, `translate3d` создает новый слой при рендеринге элемента - что, в свою очередь, должно вынудить браузер задействовать GPU не только при размытии.*

Comment: ТС, прикладывать [mcve] - это ***ваша*** задача, а не отвечающих.

Comment: очень качественный ответ. Непонятно,почему до сих пор не оценили. (:+) Может воскресенье тому виной

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, спасибо! Оценки-то ладно, а вот если автор вопроса не отметит ответ (что сделает невозможным линковку этого вопроса к дублирующим) - будет обидно, учитывая насколько легко столкнуться с проблемой мигания анимаций и переходов... это ведь "фирменная фича" вебкита :)

Comment: не стесняйтесь напоминать новичкам о возможности поблагодарить автора ответа. Бывают случаи с новичками, что они серьезно не знали о такой возможности.

Comment: У меня ничего не мигает ни в одном из браузеров, так что я так и не понял, в чём проблема) Подтормаживает в хроме — да, но не мигает (а в Firefox вообще всё гладенько)

Comment: @andreymal, ну **[вот такая ситуация](https://i.imgur.com/ynB9wRA.gifv)** в актуальном сейчас хроме (66.0.3359.181). Предлагаемое решение тоже помигивает, но не так люто :)

Comment: @yar85 видимо, это вендоспецифично или драйвероспецифично, ибо на моём линуксе так всё-таки не мигает)

Comment: @andreymal, скорее, это просто линукс такой клевый, а не винда плохая. И в винде, и на ведроиде меня первый сниппет одинаково мигает в 100% случаев (хотя спеки вроде достаточные для веба: 3570k@4Ghz/16GB/RadHD7770, и Galaxy Note 3). Вот в макоси и на линуксе глянуть не могу... из последнего есть только серверные `:(`

Comment: Хм, а в фырфырфоксе все ок даже на винде. И в мобильном тоже порядок. Хотя тормозит оно ужасно, конечно. Нипанятна... я-то думал что причина как раз в производительности, и ответ нацелен на оптимизацию (которая в хроме даже помогает, что самое прикольное).

Comment: @yar85 Спасибо, за крутой ответ) Извиняюсь что так долго не подтверждал)

Comment: @yar85 Если интересно то в Safare на Mac так же есть проблема с мерцанием... На втором примере у меня все нормально) И да, как отблагодарить?)